# Using R functions in python

Tags: python, r

I am an avid python user.  I have been programming and performing a lot of my statistics using R.  Recently, I tried to go into one of my notebooks to perform some statistical analysis.  I have written over 5000 lines of code.  Now, I have used R functions scattered everywhere throughout my program.  Unfortunately, I am unable to even use any of the functions i have written before.

This is what i have done before:

```
%load_ext rmagic
import rpy2.robjects as R
import pandas.rpy.common as com
from rpy2.robjects.packages import importr
import scipy.stats as sp
stats=importr('stats')
TSA = importr('TSA')
forecast = importr('forecast')
fUnitRoots = importr('fUnitRoots')
tseries = importr('tseries')
urca = importr('urca')
VARS = importr('vars')
zoo = importr('zoo')
aod = importr('aod')
```

Now, I can't even run any of this any more as i get an import error "r_magic extension has been moved".

Also, i have called R functions by doing the following:

```
%R acf(x)
```

Above statement no longer works.

But if i do....

```
R.r('acf(x)')
```

it works.  This seems like an annoying change i have to incorporate in my large program.  Is there a workaround towards this solution?

Thanks

Comment: What have you changed since the code stopped working?

Comment: my ipython notebook has upgraded to jupyter automatically.  Ever since the change, nothing seems to work as before.  I followed the example online on how to call R functions in python.  It seems like the %R command doesn't work anymore in ipython.  I have just went ahead with the online example and it works now.  But now i have another issue which i am going to raise in the next question

Comment: This is the problem i am running into now:
    df = com.load_data('mtcars')
    rdf2 = com.convert_to_r_dataframe(df)
    robj.globalenv[

Comment: This is the problem i am running into now:
    df = com.load_data('mtcars')
    rdf2 = com.convert_to_r_dataframe(df)
    robj.globalenv['rdf2'] = rdf2
    robj.r('y=ts(rdf2)')
    fit_full = fGarch.garchFit('~1+garch(1,1),data=y,trace=F)
For some reason, this gives me errors.  "missing value where True/False needed

Answer (score 1):

The rmagic is now in rpy2. Do:

`%load_ext rpy2.ipython`